# Consume vscode extensions as npm packages

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, vscode-extensions

#### Context:

I am writing a theme adapter for the monaco editor in order to have some Textmate based coloring. I was able to tokenize the source files, but it then takes a special theme in order to actually apply color to these new tokens.

#### Question:

Is there a way to depend on a vscode extension (`vscode/extensions/theme-defaults` for instance) ? There is a `package.json` file, but it doesn't seem to be published on `npm`.

What would you recommend me to do ? Is there plans to upload these extensions ? Am I even allowed to base myself on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no plan to publish vscode's internal extensions to npm as they are not widely consumable/useful and there's a cost to keeping them up to date

We pull in some themes or grammars from Text Mate or other open source projects in VS Code. There are not published to a package repo so we get them directly from github. You could do the same against the VS Code repo as all the built-in extensions are published under the same license as the rest of the codebase (although keep in mind that many also pull third party open source of their own).